# How to put data from ManyToManyField to choices in MultipleChoiceField

Tags: django, forms, python-3.x, models, manytomanyfield

I have a form:

```
*# dialogues.forms*

class CreateConferenceForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    participants = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=?)
    ...
```

And I need to put in choices argument instead of "?" data from friends field in this model:

```
*# persons.models*

class Person(User):
    ...
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        related_name='+',
    ) 
    ...
```

How can I do it?

Comment: are you sure you want to be using a regular form instead of a `ModelForm`?

Comment: How do you get the `Person` instance? Is it the acting user or is there some other field for it?

Comment: Person is an acting user - yes. I don't sure I use regular form because of more flexibility than ModelForm but now I decided to use ModelForm, it's really suitable for my purposes, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating an instance of a conference model with your form, you should consider using [Django's `ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/), which is designed to be used in the creation and editing of model instances.

In either case, you can use a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) to serve your purpose, which is simply a `MultipleChoiceField` backed by a queryset for its choices. You can use this field in either a standard `Form` or a `ModelForm`.

To customize the choices based on the request, you can set the queryset in your view.

For example:

forms.py

```
class CreateConferenceForm(forms.Form):
    # An initial queryset is required, this is overwritten in the view
    participants = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(Person.objects.all())
```

views.py

```
def new_conference(request):
    data = request.POST if request.method == 'POST' else None

    conference_form = CreateConferenceForm(data=data)
    conference_form.fields['participants'].queryset = my_person.friends.all()

    if data:
        if conference_form.is_valid():
            # etc

    return render...
```

Note that it is important for you to set the queryset prior to calling `is_valid` on the form, since the queryset is used in validation, and prior to sending passing the form to a template, since the queryset is used to generate the choices shown.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I decided to use ModelForm and trick with form.fields['participants'].queryset together.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
class CreateConferenceForm(forms.Form):
    """
    """
    participants = forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Pass the request in the form.
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None) 

        super(CreateConferenceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.request:
            pass

        # Get the person object according to you need. Whether from request or hard-coded.
        person = Person.objects.filter().first()
        friend_choices = [(dct['id'], dct['id']) for dct in (person.friends.values('id'))]
        self.fields['participants'].choices = friend_choices
```

As friend field objects are also Person as MamyToMany with self. you can try this also

```
class CreateConferenceForm(forms.Form):
    """
    """
    # Replace second 'id' in values_list('id', 'id') with the field in you person model.
    participants = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=list(Person.objects.filter().values_list('id', 'id')))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't know about this possibilities so thank you for sharing your knowledge.