# How to get objects like Bolean Field options? DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

thanks for your time.

By creating an object(product) i'd like to get the option to choose in a list of all my other objects (5 of them) to appear bellow the product. Like a recommended list. Although they don't have a field or category in common. I'd like to let the user of my software set the five of them manually to display for his client.
is there something like:

```
class Product (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   related_products = models.CharField(choices=Product.objects.all())
```

or something like:

```
def get_queryset (self):
   return Product.objects.all()

class Product (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   for p in queryset
     related_products = models.CharField(choices=Product.objects())
```

or like:

```
class Product (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Related_product (models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ManyToManyField` for a many-to-many relationship.

```
class Product (models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   related_products = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

More info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField

Comment: i read the docs again and kinda get it. manytomany on self will let me relate many objects with many of them selves but i'm not getting how to create the form with all products like booleanfield or choice options, call the POST method, saving the five other products as a field. i can use the modelformset_factory(extra=5) to let me pick five of them. but not getting how to save them maybe a slugfy trough the ID?

Comment: i think i'm gonna create another model  called relation_groups, that let me create groups of 6 products and in each detail page will be displayed as sugestion the other 5 ones like a full out-fit  recomended to be bought.

Comment: If you are happy with the database structure provided by the ManyToManyField, which I think solves your problem, you can have a look how to create the Form you need, for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720532/how-to-put-data-from-manytomanyfield-to-choices-in-multiplechoicefield